# Books on the experimental evidence for Special Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, history

Lately I've been interested in investigating the more intricate parts of special relativity beyond what is readily apparent on wikipedia or physics 101 videos. So, besides mathematical treatments, I want to investigate the extensive experimental support that has been built up for special relativity over the 20th and 21st centuries.

I have had my eyes on Y.Z. Zhang's *Special relativity and its experimental foundation* [seen here on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810227493).

Does anyone else have any other suggestions on further choices (Books and Papers alike) or comments on the viability or quality of the book above?

Comment: http://www.edu-observatory.org/physics-faq/Relativity/SR/experiments.html#Twin_paradox

Comment: Here is where I originally got the idea to look up Y.Z. Zhang's book and there is a huge mound of information here but I'm still wondering what other options there may be and where I should start as well as comments galore.

Comment: It's a 112 years old theory. You can see the experiments that led to SR easily explained in textbooks, like the Michelson Morley experiment. There may have been some others, but I doubt much (other than repetions of the same). Then there were experiments done to measure some predictions of SR like time dilation and so on. But it also became an integral part of nuclear physics with mass deficits and conversions to energy. So, not sure what you mean by foundation, maybe a recompliation of various experimental results, but the experimental proof is in just about everything done in modern physics

Comment: Thank you for being very vague (Sarcasm), I know that there have been many experiments constructed that have tested the theory and have been meticulously repeated but would like references or resources to attain knowledge of them. I'm kind of tired of the same, "Its well supported with thousands of experiments", and while I do not dispute that I would rather have the documents stacked a mile high on my desk than just take anyone's word on it.

Comment: Ok, you sound like you know what you want. Sorry, can't help, don't know that kind of resource. You may want to look in Scholarpedia. Also, don't know the resource but there was a famous observation/experiment where time dilation was shown to be true, with the lifetimes of muons (if I remember right) decaying as they travel down the atmosphere at relativistic speeds.

Comment: Where was an British philosopher Russel, who explained why it has to be as it is claimed by Einstein. I don’t like it, but maybe you can extract something. And yes, it is not about experiments, if you don’t find that Gedankenexperimente are experiments too. Don’t forget, to publish here the results of your search, please.

Comment: I guess if anything BOB BEE I'm asking for particular papers. I do know about the experiment or observation you are referencing but would love particular papers covering it.